# Align a View side by side, to left of and ellipsize TextView

Tags: android, view, textview, android-relativelayout, ellipsis

I have a header view in Android which has a View `vIndicator`, which need to be aligned to the left of an TextView `tvTitle`.

Since the text inside `tvTitle` can be very long for certain languages, I have used TextView property `android:ellipsize="end"`.

The header is composed of a series of titles(with elements of each tilte item clubbed inside a `RelativeLayout`); and each title is right aligned within itself (as in headers for a table of numbers).

Here is a sample xml code for 1 title element

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#333333"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv_header"
            android:background="#2078BE"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:tag="normal"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bnpp_small_text"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I am using `android:layout_weight="1"`, in order to have a equal distribution for the header items in portrait and landscape mode, across different device dimensions.

So now the problem.

When there is enough space, things are good (Right aligned as expected)
[image]

When there is not enough space, the color indicator `vIndicator` (in blue), goes off before the `tvTitle` does ellipsis.

[image]

Could it be possible make the `vIndicator` be visible even if the `tvTitle` does ellipsis?

The `vIndicator` in orange is the next item.

I have tried using a `LinearLayout`. There I could not get the `vIndicator`side by side with the `tvTitle`, even after using `android:gravity="right"`.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why don't you use drawableStart instead? - [more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableStart)

Comment: The blue thing is a View with colored background, not a drawable. Could we have a View as a drawableStart? I do not want to create a custom drawable for each header item.

Comment: I know this, but you can easily use <shape/> to generate a drawable with the corresponding attributes and then assign it to the TextView with drawableStart

Comment: That's one work around, but I would like a solution. :( I do not want to create custom drawables for each color

Comment: I'm under the assumption it was two colours, how many colours are you planning to use?

Comment: There are quite a few, 6 columns as of now. There is reference to graphical component. I know I can create the shapes, and then reference them to the graphical component colors from the colors.xml; but that would be my last alternative. and I would end up doing it for more tables to come!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141530/discussion-between-bradley-wilson-and-b-b).

Comment: [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/6108601/vygintas-b, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html cannot be applied to Views.